# How can I make child rows delete when I delete a parent row?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [UserId]                NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [TestId]                INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ExamId]                INT            NOT NULL,
    [Title]                 NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [Status]                INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TestExam] FOREIGN KEY ([ExamId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Exam] ([ExamId])
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestQuestion] (
    [TestQuestionId] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TestId]         INT           NOT NULL,
    [ThisAnswered]   BIT           DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestQuestion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestQuestionId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TestQuestion_Test] FOREIGN KEY ([TestId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Test] ([TestId])
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [TestQuestionTest_TestId_IX]
    ON [dbo].[TestQuestion]([TestId] ASC);
```

I tried to delete the parent Test but it gives me an error. Is there a way that I can modify this so it automatically deletes all the records in TestQuestion table when I delete the test from the Test table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need a cascade delete

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_TestQuestion_Test] FOREIGN KEY ([TestId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Test] ([TestId]) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**EDIT**

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestQuestion] drop constraint [FK_TestQuestion_Test];

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestQuestion]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TestQuestion_Test] FOREIGN KEY ([TestId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Test] ([TestId]) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8883f)

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there a way that I can modify the constraint or would i have to drop it ?

Comment: @Melina you'll need to drop and recreate.

Comment: @Melina another way would be to add a second foreign key constraint with cascade delete (with another name), and than drop the old one (without cascade delete). But that's only needed if you're in production environment, without possible downtime.